# Spring 5.1.5.RELEASE what should i think to chose a JVM version

Tags: java, spring, jvm

I am having an application running on JAVA - AIX platform, I am trying to move my spring application to Spring version 5.1.5.RELEASE.

I cannot upgrade my JVM which is currently in version 'J9VM - R28_20170209_0201_B336038'

The application does run in the above JVM version, but I am not sure if I have to upgrade to the latest JVM too to benefit on the latest Spring version!?

Is there any documentation on the JVM to chose for a spring version?

PS: My application does not work on any higher JVM version, which I have to sort out first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [JDK Version Range](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions#jdk-version-range) on the [Spring Framework Versions](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Spring-Framework-Versions) page, which currently says:

> - Spring Framework 5.1.x: JDK 8-12
> - Spring Framework 5.0.x: JDK 8-10
> - Spring Framework 4.3.x: JDK 6-8
>
> We fully test and support Spring on Long-Term Support (LTS) releases of the JDK, i.e. currently JDK 8 and 11 (both with a lifetime until 2023). Additionally, there is support for intermediate releases such as JDK 9/10 or the upcoming JDK 12 on a best-effort basis, meaning that we accept bug reports and will try to address them as far as technically possible but won't provide any service level guarantees.
>
> *Please upgrade to Spring Framework 5.1 (and the corresponding Spring Boot 2.1) for JDK 11 support, as the common Long-Term Support migration path from JDK 8. No earlier Spring versions are officially supported on JDK 11, in particular not with JDK 11 bytecode level. Note that third-party components might not fully support JDK 11 yet, so you are likely to be limited in your full-stack options.*

Comment: Thanks @Andreas, So as long I have JDK 8 I don't have to worry about my JVM version. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong.